# Parsing Java String type Error

Tags: java, parsing

What i'm trying to do is incorporate interface methods to complete a task given the variables inside of a string. The string i'm given, "s" can be made up numbers, +, -, and * symbols. The integer return is fairly easy as all i'm doing is returning an integer interface method of that int. However, for the other 3 symbols, I need to recursively incorporate a method to find the left and right nodes. I've posted my code below...

```
public static Expression parseString( String s ) {
        String[] parse = s.split("\\s+");
        String[] parsecopy;
        Expression exp1;
        Expression exp2;

        if(s == null) {

            return null;
        }

        if(parse[0].equals("+")) {
            exp1 = parseString(parse[0]);
            parsecopy = Arrays.copyOfRange(parse, 2, parse.length);
            exp2 = parseString(parsecopy);
            return new AddExpression(exp1, exp2);
        }
        else if() {
```

The problem - So my code creates a copy of the original string to find the next item in that string. I do this by using the Array function, copyOfRange(). However, when I want to call exp2 = parseString(parsecopy), i'm receiving an error because parseString takes in a string argument which has to be of the type String[]. The reason i'm trying to get parsecopy instead of parsecopy[0] is because parsecopy wouldn't create an endless loop and I would actually be able to iterate through the string.

```
Error code - The method parseString(String) in the type Parse is not applicable for the arguments (String[])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(parse[0].equals("+")) {
            exp1 = parseString(parse[0]);
            parsecopy = Arrays.copyOfRange(parse, 2, parse.length);
            exp2 = parseString(parsecopy);
            return new AddExpression(exp1, exp2);
        }
```

> exp1 = parseString(parse[0]);

you are doing recursive calling here.

Comment: the problem is i'm getting an endless while loop at parse[0]

Comment: and it requires that I must do parsecopy[0] in replacement to parsecopy

Answer (score 0):

Since the parameter you pass to split is a regex, you can simply do:

```
String[] ss = "12121+34234 *23423 -123123 *123123-12312+1231231-123123".split("\\s?[\\+\\-\\*]\\s?");
```

this way you split your string wherever you got a +, - , or * (possibly with a whitespace after or before).

And please do the null-check of the string before split it :D

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to check parse[1] equals "+" rather than parse[0].
You would expect 1 + 2 rather than + 1 2.